# Query to select min and max date for every employee clock in and clock out and display null when not found

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

| Card_ID | Date_Entry | Status_Entry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-01 07:50:05 | IN |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-01 17:00:07 | OUT |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-01 07:56:00 | IN |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-01 17:01:15 | OUT |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-01 07:58:20 | IN |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-01 08:00:15 | IN |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-01 17:02:00 | OUT |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-02 07:55:05 | IN |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-02 17:02:07 | OUT |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-02 07:50:00 | IN |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-02 17:00:10 | OUT |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-02 07:59:20 | IN |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-02 08:03:15 | OUT |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-02 17:03:15 | OUT |

I want is to select row between date for example I want to display attendance from 2024-01-01 until 2024-01-03, and display all date range whether the employee entry found or not like this:

| Date_Log | Card_ID | Clock_In | Clock_Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 | 5001201 | 2024-01-01 07:50:05 | 2024-01-01 17:00:07 |
| 2024-01-01 | 5001202 | 2024-01-01 07:56:00 | 2024-01-01 17:01:15 |
| 2024-01-01 | 5001203 | 2024-01-01 07:58:20 | NULL |
| 2024-01-01 | 5001204 | 2024-01-01 08:00:15 | 2024-01-01 17:02:00 |
| 2024-01-02 | 5001201 | 2024-01-02 07:55:05 | 2024-01-02 17:02:07 |
| 2024-01-02 | 5001202 | 2024-01-02 07:50:00 | 2024-01-02 17:00:10 |
| 2024-01-02 | 5001203 | 2024-01-02 07:59:20 | 2024-01-02 08:03:15 |
| 2024-01-02 | 5001204 | NULL | 2024-01-02 17:03:15 |
| 2024-01-03 | 5001201 | NULL | NULL |
| 2024-01-03 | 5001202 | NULL | NULL |
| 2024-01-03 | 5001203 | NULL | NULL |
| 2024-01-03 | 5001204 | NULL | NULL |

Are there someone who can help me with the correct query in mysql or sql server? thank you in advance!

Comment: Would a checkin and checkout always occur strictly on the same calendar date (when both do occur) ?

Comment: mysql or sql server?  which are you using?

Comment: clock_in and clock_out can occur on the same day if the work shift is shift 1 and 2. if shift 3, then clock_in at 10 pm and checkout at 6 am the next day

Comment: I'm using mysql @ysth

Comment: I have removed the `SQL-Server` tag

Comment: Without a shift_id or some mechanism to mark the IN and OUT for a shift, how do we know if the IN and OUT during the same day belong to the same shift. e.g A clock-in at 7 am and a clock-out at 11 pm could mean an overtime in 1 shift or 2 separate shifts in which the emp forgot the clock-out in shift 1 and clock-in in shift2?

Comment: @blabla_bingo actually this is a simple system, where status_entry is the marker. if status_entry is 'IN' then it is the clock in, and if status_entry is 'OUT' then it is the clock out. if the start time is 21 o'clock or later, then it means shift 3 where the clock out time will be at 6 o'clock in the morning the next day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a reference table that stores all the distinct `Card_ID` with assigned date ranges that you required. In MySQL, you'll probably end up with something like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE datelog AS (
  SELECT MIN(DATE(Date_Entry)) AS Date_log, MAX(DATE(Date_Entry)) AS MaxDate 
     FROM mytable UNION ALL
  SELECT Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MaxDate 
     FROM datelog WHERE Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= MaxDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY),
leftTable AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Card_ID, Date_log
     FROM mytable CROSS JOIN datelog)
SELECT  a.Date_log,
        a.Card_ID,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='IN' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_in,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='OUT' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_out
   FROM leftTable a
   LEFT JOIN mytable b 
     ON a.Card_ID=b.Card_ID AND a.Date_log=DATE(b.Date_entry)
  GROUP BY a.Date_log, a.Card_ID
  ORDER BY a.Date_log, a.Card_ID;
```

There are 3 parts in the query, the first part is:

```
/*part 1*/
WITH RECURSIVE datelog AS (
  SELECT MIN(DATE(Date_Entry)) AS Date_log, MAX(DATE(Date_Entry)) AS MaxDate 
     FROM mytable UNION ALL
  SELECT Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY, MaxDate 
     FROM datelog WHERE Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= MaxDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY),
```

`WITH RECURSIVE` gives you a date range in row. In here, I'm using the `MIN()` value for your table's `Date_entry` as the first date and get `MAX()` as the last date. However, you did mention until `2024-01-03` so I added `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` into the `MaxDate` value. The reason why do it like this is because I wanted the date range to be dynamically generated. You can specify the date range directly if you want like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE datelog AS (
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS Date_log UNION ALL
  SELECT Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
     FROM datelog WHERE Date_log + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2024-01-03'),
```

For the second part, we're using normal `cte` to generate the reference table:

```
/*part 2*/
leftTable AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Card_ID, Date_log
     FROM mytable CROSS JOIN datelog)
```

What this do is taking the result from the first `RECURSIVE cte` and `CROSS JOIN` the distinct values of `Card_ID` data from your table. The result of this:

```
+---------+------------+
| Card_ID |  Date_log  |
+---------+------------+
| 5001201 | 2024-01-01 |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-02 |
| 5001201 | 2024-01-03 |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-01 |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-02 |
| 5001202 | 2024-01-03 |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-01 |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-02 |
| 5001203 | 2024-01-03 |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-01 |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-02 |
| 5001204 | 2024-01-03 |
+---------+------------+
```

Now that we have the reference table, we can proceed to do a `LEFT JOIN`. To get the result of `Clock_in` and `Clock_out`, we'll use `MIN()` and `MAX()` combined with `CASE` expression on the `Status_Entry` value.

```
/*part 3*/
SELECT  a.Date_log,
        a.Card_ID,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='IN' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_in,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='OUT' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_out
   FROM leftTable a
   LEFT JOIN mytable b 
     ON a.Card_ID=b.Card_ID AND a.Date_log=DATE(b.Date_entry)
  GROUP BY a.Date_log, a.Card_ID
  ORDER BY a.Date_log, a.Card_ID;
```

Now, the above solution only works on MySQL v8+ (or MariaDB 10.2/10.3+) and above so if you're using older version, then you can try this one:

```
SELECT  leftTable.Date_log,
        leftTable.Card_ID,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='IN' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_in,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Status_Entry='OUT' THEN Date_Entry END) AS Clock_out
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Card_ID, Date_log
          FROM mytable CROSS JOIN
              (SELECT '2024-01-01' AS Date_log UNION
               SELECT '2024-01-02' UNION
               SELECT '2024-01-03') datelog) leftTable
   LEFT JOIN mytable b 
     ON leftTable.Card_ID=b.Card_ID AND leftTable.Date_log=DATE(b.Date_entry)
  GROUP BY leftTable.Date_log, leftTable.Card_ID
  ORDER BY leftTable.Date_log, leftTable.Card_ID;
```

It's the same idea but this is using derived table instead of `cte` and it should be able to run on all MySQL version.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LhOX_Ghn)